# Excel VBA: Copy a row if cells contain certain data

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to coding in general, but here goes:

I have a huge list of membershipdata which I am trying to organize. This is going to be done weekly as the data is variable, so I am trying to automate the work a bit.

My problem is, I want to copy an entire row of data if a specific cell contains a specific text.

I have been able to do so using this code:

```
Sub OK()

Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Status")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OK")

j = 2
For Each c In Source.Range("F1:F300")
    If c = "Yes" Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

However, I want to use multiple conditions i.e. I only want the row to be copied if *both* column E and I contains "Yes".

My initial guess was this, but it doesnt seem right:

```
For Each c In Source.Range("F1:F300") AND Source.Range("I1:I300")
```

How can i add a condition to my code? I have tried using "and", but cant get it right it seems.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add another Range in the way you have to a loop. Instead loop the one range as you originally put and as the additional range you want to check matches on a row by row basis but differs in terms of column use OFFSET to test the column I value in the same row. As below:

```
If c = "Yes" And c.Offset(0, 3) = "Yes"
```

So all together:

```
Sub OK()

Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Status")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OK")

j = 2
For Each c In Source.Range("F1:F300")
    If c = "Yes" And c.Offset(0, 3) = "Yes" Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly! Thank you :)